# Convert Image Data URI to Image PHP

Tags: php, image, base64, fpdf, data-uri

I have a data uri variable in php

```
$imageURL  = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAJYCAYAAACadoJwAAAgAElEQ…ACIiACIiAC5U1AAqS891erEwEREAEREAEREAEREIFAEfj/bfXX..."
```

I am trying to insert this into a pdf using fpdf for which I need to convert this into a image I guess. I tried doing something like

```
base64_decode($imageURL);
```

but this does not work. How I successfully insert this data uri into pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$image_content = base64_decode(str_replace("data:image/png;base64,","",$imageURL)); // remove "data:image/png;base64,"
$tempfile = tmpfile(); // create temporary file
fwrite($tempfile, $image_content); // fill data to temporary file
$metaDatas = stream_get_meta_data($tempfile);
$tmpFilename = $metaDatas['uri'];
```

Now you can use that image into fpdf like:

```
$pdf->Image($tmpFilename,null,null,0,0);
```

Or you can specify image type by adding image type parameter like this:

```
$pdf->Image($tmpFilename,null,null,0,0,'PNG');
```

Please check to http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm

Comment: PHP temporary file produces *.tmp file.
FPDF Image using file extention to recognise image type, unless specified on parameter http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm
So, use like this:
`$pdf->Image($tmpFilename,null,null,0,0,'PNG');`

Comment: *extension (sorry, typo)

Answer (score 1):

Usually we have something like

```
data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==
```

So, after first comma all data will be pure file source. Below we are removing first part "data:text/plain;base64" and after make a glue string again, as commas can be in the middle of string, for example. So, providing the code:

```
$file = explode(',', $file);
unset($file[0]);
$file = implode(',', $file);
```

Another variant is to find first comma by substr or like that and just cut this part of text, maybe it works faster than implode/explode.

With result, you can store the file:

```
file_put_contents('filename.ext', base64_decode(result));
```

Comment: Updated in answer